# Jquery Plugin Undefined In Module

Tags: module, magento-1

I'm trying to load a jQuery plugin, tinyCarousel, for use on the page. The jQuery library is included as follows in the `layout.xml` file:

```
<layout>
    ...
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="jquery/general/jqueryEnabled">
                <script>jquery-1.10.1.min.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    ...
</layout>
```

I've checked in the browser and the library is definitely present. Next, tinyCarousel.js is loaded from another `layout.xml` file:

```
<layout>
    ...
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>jquery.tinyCarousel.min.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    ...
</layout>
```

Again, that script is present on the page and in the correct order (after the jQuery library). On the page, I am trying to call tinyCarousel as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    if (jQuery === 'undefined') {
        jQuery.noConflict();
    }

    var container = <?php echo "'#" . $containerClass . "'"; ?>;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(container).tinycarousel({ interval: true, duration: 300, display: 1 });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

The error returned is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinycarousel'
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

This is embarrassing - the theme for magento already included jQuery. I found it riiiight at the top of the `<head>`. Thanks anyway.